# What is the biblical basis for the argument that the 'mission of Jesus' was to 'restore humanity to a state of sinless purity'?

Tags: life-of-jesus, words-of-jesus, historical-jesus

> The teachings of the Unification Church are based on the Bible but with new interpretations, and Moon saw his role as completing the unfulfilled mission of Jesus **to restore humanity to a state of “sinless” purity.**

[Unification Church - Reported by 'The Independent' 17 Feb 2013](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/thousands-marry-in-first-moonie-wedding-since-founder-s-death-8498419.html)

And what is the biblical basis for explaining how this was to be done ?

Comment: This appears to be two questions, not one.  The first is whether humanity is to be restored to a state of sinless purity, and the second is about the Unification Church.

Comment: @Mary No, I am not relating the second question to any specific body. I am relating the second question to the first. It is a two-part question. I have not drawn attention (in my question) to the actual _source_ of the thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy of Moon's "Divine Principle" is on my bookshelves (long story). I could report on the way he contrives his argument (which is not very Biblical), but I would need a little time to re-study his chapter on "The Second Advent of the Messiah". This can only be a temporary answer.

As a sample of his methods, I can briefly outline his case for the claim that the new Christ, replacing Jesus, must appear in Korea. Firstly, "The Bible teaches" that the nation which will replace the Jewish nation lies in the east. This is based on Revelation ch7 vv2-4 ("Another angel ascended from the rising of the sun"). Obviously not Japan, because of the war. Obviously not China, because of communism. That leaves Korea.

The Korean individual who might meet this expectation is not named in the book. But he would crate a new Eden by transforming the culture of Korea and this would spread through the world. Final sentence; "In this way, the whole of mankind will become one people speaking one language, thus establishing one world of one culture".

This is what Jesus was supposed to have done, based on the Jewish nation, and that is why the mission of Jesus is to be regarded as a failure. But this is from an earlier chapter, full of jargon which I have forgotten.

P.s. I add this quotation from a "Six Hour Lecture" booklet version, which answers the question about the mission of Jesus but still without Biblical backing; "The Messiah must stand before God as the origin of the ideal individual and furthermore establish the ideal family where the love of God can dwell, and go on to restore the ideal nation and world which would be the originally intended Kingdom of Heaven on earth."

Moon taught that the death of Jesus on the cross marked the failure of his mission, which was why one more final Messiah would be needed. Unfortunately for his teaching, Moon also died without achieving that mission, which technically identifies him as another failure.

Comment: So, from which Korea do the proponents of this doctrine say they expect such things - the Korea which produces ICBMs and fissile material, or the one which produces K-pop ? Or is it both ? I up-voted, but I am still awaiting the biblical support for 'the restoration of humanity to sinless purity' . . . . . . .

Comment: Moon was a South Korean and meant himself, but he may have seen uniting the Peninsula under himself as part of his mission. I should warn you that genuine Biblical support will be hard to find, but it is essentially a doctrine of salvation by works. The new saints will devote themsleves to the will of God and this will transform society, which is how sin disappears from the world.

Comment: @Nigel J I think the short answer on Biblical support is that his argument depends on finding comvoluted esoteric pattrens in Biblical events, rather than on Biblical texts.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus “mission” was to do the will of his heavenly Father who sent him and this was accomplished.  The resurrection proves that, as well as proving that Jesus has destroyed the devil’s work – which was to prevent the Messiah, the Christ, who is the Son of God, from taking upon himself the sin of the world. Jesus has also defeated the power of death which is one consequence of sin.

Please note, however, that is not quite the same thing as saying “Jesus’ mission was to restore humanity to a state of sinless purity.”  That expression suggests that Jesus failed because humanity has not yet been restored to a state of sinless purity.  That expression suggests that more still has to be done.

***According to the Bible, one reason God sent His Son into our world was to provide purification for sins (1 John 1:7).***

***Another reason the Son of God appeared was to destroy the devil’s work (1 John 3:8).***

***The following scriptures (paraphrased) show how, and by whom, it was to be done:***

1 John 1:7 – Only the blood of Jesus can purify us from all sin

Hebrews 1:3 – Only Jesus can provide purification for sins

Hebrews 9:26-27 – Jesus has appeared once for all to do away with sin by his sacrifice

Romans3:24 – Redemption came by the sacrifice of Jesus Christ

John 1:29 – Jesus takes away the sin of the world

John 3:16-18 – God gave his one and only Son that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life. God sent his Son... to save the world through him. Whoever believes in him is not condemned.

John 14:6 – Jesus is the only way – there is no other

Acts 4:12 – Salvation is found in no-one other than Jesus Christ. There is no other name by which people can be saved.

2 Corinthians 5:21 – Jesus was without sin and that is why he alone could “be sin for us, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God.”

2 Timothy 1:8-10 – God’s grace has been revealed through the appearing of our Saviour, Christ Jesus

Revelation 5:9 – Jesus’ blood has purchased men for God

***Upon the death and resurrection of Christ Jesus, that “mission” was accomplished.  With His dying breath He cried out “It is finished!” (John 19:30).***

Far from suggesting that the death of Jesus proved he had failed, his death (and subsequent resurrection) proved Satan had failed in his “mission”, which was to prevent God’s will from being done.  The resurrected, glorified and triumphant Christ now sits at the right-hand of God in heaven, waiting for the time when he will crush all his enemies.  After that God will establish a new heaven and a new earth.  Sin, death, suffering and tears will have ended and God will dwell with mankind.  That is the culmination of Jesus’ ministry here on earth.  It is future.

To suggest that Jesus failed in his “mission” is to deny the efficacy of his sacrifice, his resurrection, to call God a liar, and to usurp His authority and power.  It is to suggest that another “Christ” is needed.  That is heresy.